# Read Events from EventHub in Unity3D and HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-eventhub, hololens

We are trying to show events from an Azure EventHub in our HoloLens application. When we run our project in Unity 3D, it works and paint the data from the events.

But when we deploy the same solution on the HoloLens, we don't receive events and also we don't receive any error.

Here is the code:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;
    using TMPro;
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;
    using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
    using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor;
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    
    namespace Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Examples.Demos
    {
        [AddComponentMenu("Scripts/MRTK/Examples/SliderLunarLander")]
        public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
        {
            [SerializeField]
            
            public Animator helice2;
            public TextMeshPro textovelocidad;
            public EventProcessorClient processor;
            public BlobContainerClient storageClient;
    
            private const string storageConnectionString = "XXXX";
            private const string blobContainerName = "XXXX";
            private const string eventHubsConnectionString = "XXXX";
            private const string consumerGroup = "hololens";
            private const string EventHubName = "XXXX";
    
            private float? speedValue;
            private string errorText = string.Empty;
            private CancellationToken cancellationToken;
    
            async void Start()
        {
            errorText = "Init EventReader...";

            storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, blobContainerName);

            var clientOptions = new EventProcessorClientOptions()
            {
                ConnectionOptions = new EventHubConnectionOptions ()
                { 
                    TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
                }
            };

            processor = new EventProcessorClient
            (
                storageClient,
                consumerGroup,
                eventHubsConnectionString,
                clientOptions
            );            
            
            processor.ProcessEventAsync += processEventHandler;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += processErrorHandler;

            errorText = "Start EventReader...";

            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

            try
            {
                //The processor performs its work in the background; block until cancellation
                //to allow processing to take place.
                errorText = "Infinite Loop...";
                await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException tcex)
            {
                //This is expected when the delay is canceled.
                textoError.text = tcex.Message;
            }

            //Debug.Log("Device client initialited...");            
        }

        public void OnSliderUpdated(SliderEventData eventData)
        {           
                helice2.speed = eventData.NewValue;            
        }

        async void OnDestroy()
        {
            try
            {
                await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                //To prevent leaks, the handlers should be removed when processing is complete.
                processor.ProcessEventAsync -= processEventHandler;
                processor.ProcessErrorAsync -= processErrorHandler;
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (speedValue != null)
            {
                helice2.speed = float.Parse(speedValue.ToString());
            }
            
            textovelocidad.text = (helice2.speed).ToString("F2") + " r.p.m.";
            textovelocidad.text += " | " + infoText; 
            textoError.text = errorText;
        }

        async Task processEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                // Write the body of the event to the console window
                //Console.WriteLine("\tRecevied event: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray()));
                infoText = " Event Received ";

                string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray());

                var deviceTurbine = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DeviceTurbine>(json);
                
                if (deviceTurbine != null)
                {
                    speedValue = deviceTurbine.speed;
                }

                // Update checkpoint in the blob storage so that the app receives only new events the next time it's run
                await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync(eventArgs.CancellationToken);

                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception from handler code
                // Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
                errorText = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        Task processErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                // Write details about the error to the console window
                //Console.WriteLine($"\tPartition '{ eventArgs.PartitionId}': an unhandled exception was encountered. This was not expected to happen.");
                //Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.Message);
                errorText = eventArgs.Exception.Message;
            }
            catch
            {
                // Handle the exception from handler code
                errorText = eventArgs.Exception.Message;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        }
    
        class DeviceTurbine
        {
            private float _speed;
            private DateTime _timestamp;
            private string _deviceId;
            public float speed
            {
                get; set;
            }
    
            public DateTime timestamp
            {
                get;set;
            }
    
            public string deviceId
            {
                get; set;
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say that you don't receive an error, does that mean that you're not seeing your `processEventHandler` fire?   I can't claim knowledge of Hololens, so I'm curious if the `Console.WriteLine` would display the information.

Comment: As a test, can you also check the `IsRunning` property of the processor before you block in the `Task.Delay`.    If the processor fails to start, it will invoke the error handler and will also not set the property.   I'm curious if the processor is failing to start and the error isn't being surfaced by your handler.

Comment: Not much to go on but speculation, but I suspect that you that you may need to use WebSockets rather than TCP on the device to allow communication.  If you want to try making that change, an example can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_EventHubsClients.md#using-web-sockets

Comment: @JesseSquire I changed to WebSockets, but not luck :-( I'm not seeing processEventHandler fire and also processErrorHandler is not firing.

Comment: Can you clarify how you're determining that the `processErrorHandler` is not firing?   I'm trying to understand if we're debugging and not seeing things called or if we're relying on the `Console.Writeline` and that is not displaying as we're expecting.

Comment: @JesseSquire The program runs Ok on Unity, but when we deploy to HoloLens the program is running but processErrorHandler nor processEventHandler are firing. I modify the program to paint any error message on a TextBox on the screen.

Comment: It definitely seems to be environmental.   Before you block on the `Task.Delay`,  what does the processor's `IsRunning` property return?    We're probably also at the point where looking at the internal logs would help.   I'd advise hooking up the `AzureEventSourceListener` to the processor, as demonstrated by this sample:
https://github.com/jsquire/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md